# Doxygen typedef struct

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

I've got the problem that doxygen will auto document all typedef structs from header files which are included in the configurations. They are listed as "Data structures" in the HTML documentation on the sidebar. Which option is needed to deactivate the auto documentation from structs? Thanks!

Comment: You can use [`EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_exclude_symbols) option to exclude specific func, classes etc. The `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` tag can be used to specify one or more symbol names  that should be excluded from the output.

Comment: Thanks tho. Maybe not best practice but its working

Comment: Please always also mention the version the doxygen version you are using, the settings, different from the default doxygen setting, and whether or not you documented the typedef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your struct definiton goes in the header file doxygen will document it automatically unless you define your structure in related C file; in this case it'd be private and could be prevented to output by setting the following options to `NO`:

- [`EXTRACT_ALL`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_all)
- [`EXTRACT_PRIVATE`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_private)
- [`EXTRACT_STATIC`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_static)

But since the definition resides in your header file you can hide it either by setting the `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` to your struct symbol/definiton name(s) or as an alternative to the `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` option you can use [`hideinitializer`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdhideinitializer) command in the comment section of your struct type in the source code.